# Insert multiple image at random time on video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I insert multiple images at random time on video using ffmpeg?

I have some pictures and I want to add these to my video at random time, for example picture 01 at 5s, picture 02 at 20s.

Answer (score 3):

Find this

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -i watermark2.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,1,2)' [tmp]; [tmp][2:v] overlay=20:20:enable='between(t,2,3)'" output.mp4